# i have two table a and b. compuny name,productname same . how can i jon

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
table_a
.........................................
cmp_name    pro_name    purchase
a                 x1        5
a                 x2        7
b                 p1        8
a                  x1       8
b                  p2       12
b                  p1       6
a                 x1        3


table_b
.........................................
cmp_name    pro_name    sale
a                 x1        3
a                 x2        1
b                 p1        4
a                 x1        3
b                 p2        2
b                 p1        4
a                 x1        1


result
.........................................
cmp_name    pro_name    Total_pur   Total_sale      stock
a                  x1       16              7        9
a                  x2       7               1        6
b                  p1       14              8        6
b                  p2       12               2       10
```

how can i do this

Comment: Could you pls do some research on ` left join`?

Answer (score 0):

try the below query, but you must have a better design for this case

```html
SELECT 
    table_a.cmp_name,
    table_a.pro_name c,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(table_a.purchase)
        FROM
            table_a
        WHERE
            table_a.pro_name = c) AS Total_pur,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(table_b.sale)
        FROM
            table_b
        WHERE
            table_b.pro_name = c) AS Total_sale,
    ((SELECT 
            SUM(table_a.purchase)
        FROM
            table_a
        WHERE
            table_a.pro_name = c) - (SELECT 
            SUM(table_b.sale)
        FROM
            table_b
        WHERE
            table_b.pro_name = c)) AS stock
FROM
    table_a
        LEFT JOIN
    table_b ON table_a.cmp_name = table_b.cmp_name
GROUP BY table_a.cmp_name , table_a.pro_name
```

Comment: Please do avoid using the old style join in query

Comment: right, I have changed the method of joining Thanks

Comment: sorry, the result is not correct in this query

Comment: check the new query, I have change it

Comment: thank you very much. its great to be able to join such a beautiful platform.

Answer (score 0):

you need to perform a group by `cmp_name` and `pro_name` for both `purchase` and `sale` table. This is to get total purchase and sale by `cmp_name` and `pro_name`

After that use  `purchase` table `LEFT JOIN` to `sale` table. (cause you might have item with purchases but without sale)

```
select a.cmp_name, 
       a.pro_name, 
       a.purchase, 
       b.sale, 
       stock = a.purchase - isnull(b.sale, 0)
from   (
           select cmp_name, pro_name, purchase = sum(purchase)
           from   table_a
           group by cmp_name, pro_name
       ) a
       left join 
       (
           select cmp_name, pro_name, sale = sum(sale)
           from   table_b 
           group by cmp_name, pro_name
       ) b                  on  a.cmp_name = b.cmp_name
                            and a.pro_name = b.pro_name
order by a.cmp_name, a.pro_name
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5918f0ff8188404032054d5e7187caa6)